# AES encryption error "last block incomplete in decryption"

Tags: java, android, encryption

In my project I have tried to implement AES decryption of a JSON file gives the error "last block incomplete in decryption". The file definitely doesn't have any problem.

When I try on a non-encrypted

```
Log.i("dec",decrypt(encrypt(finalJson)));
```

it works. So there isn't any problem in the functions. But when I do

```
Log.i("dec",decrypt(finalJson));
```

in the encrypted file it give's the error. I tried 4 different AES implementations and all gave the same problem. The file is opened like this

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(file[0]);

        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        finalJson = new String(buffer)
```

So what is the problem ?

```
09-10 19:05:04.864      867-867/com.popat.quiz W/System.err﹕ javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
09-10 19:05:04.864      867-867/com.popat.quiz W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:850)
09-10 19:05:04.864      867-867/com.popat.quiz W/System.err﹕ at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
```

**Edit**
Here's my encryption code

```
public String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    String message1 = Base64.encodeToString(message.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    String salt = "1abcdefgjijklmno";
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(message1.getBytes());
    String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encrypted;
}

//Decryption
public String decrypt(String message) throws Exception {

    String salt = "1abcdefgjijklmno";
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(message.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    String decoded = new String(Base64.decode(decryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT));
    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: add your encryption code...

Comment: I added it but pretty sure the problem's not there.

Comment: `decrypt(finalJson)` - So you're trying to decrypt `finalJson`, which is not encrypted? Or `decrypt(encrypt(finalJson))` - You're encrypting the already-encrypted `finalJson` again and then decrypting it?

Comment: ok for encryption FileOutputStream or CipherOutputStream check cipherOutputStream.flush();
           cipherOutputStream.close();   it

Comment: I copied the log from encrypt(finalJson) and manually put it in the finalJson. I then tried decrypt(finalJson) and that is when the error came.

Comment: @user3676184 I'm new to android and encryption so no idea what you meant. Could you point to a link ?

Comment: *"I tried 4 different AES implementations and all gave the same problem."* Which means that the problem is somewhere else. You haven't shown the part of the code that might have the issue.

Comment: There is no other part related to decryption. I showed you how I opened the file,  the encryption functions and the function call when it worked and when it didn't. What more should I show ?

Comment: You method of reading in the file is flawed, though it *may* work. You should simply read in data until EOF. You write the data you read in into a ByteArrayOutputStream if you don't know the length in advance. Also, you should never use defaults. Use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")' rather than what you did. Use `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` instead of `String.getBytes()`, and use `new String(<byte array>, "UTF-8")`. None of these may be the cause of your problem, but they're all good practices to adhere to.